# Flattening a protobufs-net contract

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I want to flatten a type hierarchy used to define a protobuf-net contract where we currently have something along the lines of:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SubClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
   [ProtoMember(100)]
   public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then refactor this to

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SubClass
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }

   [ProtoMember(100)]
   public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Such that instances serialised before the refactoring are successfully deserialised. Is this possible simply by picking the correct indexes or do I need to do something more?

Comment: as a side-note; it is worth using smaller field-numbers when possible; in particular, 1-31 are cheap; 100 is slightly more expensive (1 extra byte per field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, inheritance in protobuf-net is implemented in a way that is fundamentally a multi-level operation. It isn't trivial to model it, and frankly it might be easier to use something like auto-mapper, i.e. load the data into the *old* model; map it to the *new* model; serialize the new model. Note that this is a breaking change, and the data will not be compatible after that. You could, however, do it in one model **if** you can live with a little bit of ugly (although note I had to give different field-numbers to make it work):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class NewClass
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; 

    [ProtoMember(100)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)] // this 1 is from ProtoMember
    private Shim ShimForSerialization { get { return new Shim(this); } }

    // this disables the shim during serialiation; only Prop1 and Prop2 will
    // be written
    public bool ShouldSerializeShimForSerialization() { return false; }

    [ProtoContract]
    private class Shim {
        private readonly NewClass parent;
        public Shim(NewClass parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Prop1 {
            get { return parent.Prop1;}
            set { parent.Prop1 = value;}
        }

    }
}
```